# Vertical bar that extends to length of longer among two adjacent divs

Tags: html, css

I have two adjacent `div`(s). I need to separate them by vertical bars.

So I use the following css :

```
#div1{
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
#div2{
}
```

But the problem is that the height of both the `div`(s) isn't fixed. Sometimes `div1` is longer & at other times, `div2`. & thus the vertical bar created by `border` css property is not visible to full length of `div1`+ `div2`. How can I create a vertical bar that has height equal to longer among the 2 `div`(s).

Not looking for a javascript solution.

Comment: Wrap both divs in a container div and set the border on that div

Comment: Misread ur request... Could u set the right divs margin-left -1px so the divs share inner borders and div 1 set border-right 1px and dive 2 set border-left 1px. Both would draw a border but it would appear as one

Comment: Does making a third div in between the two divs and setting its height as per your requirement suffices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion from the comment

```
#div1 {border-right:1px solid #ccc;}
#div2 {
     border-left:1px solid #ccc;
     margin-left:-1px;
}
```

Comment: Trying to answer questions on an iPad in a timely fashion was a bad decision!

Comment: good questions & good answers are always welcome and up voted, irrespective of timelines..so even if ur late and u answered question in a better way ..u can always gain up votes for that ..+1...although Kolink is the first one to answer :P

Comment: Yah I can't blame him, was my own fault.

Comment: @DylanHayes: No fault :) I'll accept yours(with a +1), as you answered first even if in the form of a comment:)

Comment: @DylanHayes here, people are generous as well :)

Comment: Very cool, Ty! It's all about helping and learning in the long run anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#div1 {border-right:1px solid #ccc;}
#div2 {
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left:-1px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fE3Nt/)

Comment: Um... no I didn't. Nowhere do I create a wrapper div.

Comment: @DylanHayes You should've answered than